# How to find the index of an element in the AVX vector?

Tags: x86, intrinsics, avx

I am trying to write a hardware accelerated hash table using AVX, where each bucket has a fixed size (AVX vector size). The question arose of how to implement a quick search by vector.

Incomplited possible solution:

```
example target hash: 2

<1  7  8  9  2  6  3  5>  //  vector of hashes
<2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2>  //  mask vector of target hash
------------------------  //  equality comparison
<0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0>  //  result of comparison
<0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7>  //  vector of indexes
------------------------  //  and operation
<0  0  0  0  4  0  0  0>  //  index of target hash
```

**How to extract index of target hash from last vector?**

---

Another (slow) possible solution using a scalar product:

```
<1  7  8  9  2  6  3  5>  //  vector of hashes
<2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2>  //  mask vector of target hash
------------------------  //  equality comparison
<0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0>  //  result of comparison
<0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7>  //  vector of indexes
------------------------  //  dot
            -4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The appropriate horizontal operation for this is MOVMSKPS, which extracts a mask from an XMM/YMM vector (basically, it gathers the top bit from each lane). Once you've got that, you can do TZCNT or LZCNT to get to an index.

Example:

```
#include <intrin.h>
#include <immintrin.h>

int getIndexOf(int const values[8], int target)
{
    __m256i valuesSimd = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i const*)values);
    __m256i targetSplatted = _mm256_set1_epi32(target);
    __m256i equalBits = _mm256_cmpeq_epi32(valuesSimd, targetSplatted);
    unsigned equalMask = _mm256_movemask_ps(_mm256_castsi256_ps(equalBits));
    int index = _tzcnt_u32(equalMask);
    return index;
}
```

Comment: Would be nice to update this answer with a version using the new masked vector instructions and ideally extended to AVX-512